# Representation theoretic proof of the dual Jacobi-Trudi identity

Tags: combinatorics, representation-theory

Let $\lambda=(\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n)$ and $\mu=(\mu_1,\ldots,\mu_n)$ be integer partitions such that $\mu \subseteq \lambda$. Let $e_k$ be the $k$th elementary symmetric function, which is also the Schur symmetric function $s_{(1^k)}$. The dual Jacobi-Trudi identity says that
$$s_{\lambda/\mu} = \det\left(e_{\lambda'_i-\mu'_j-i-j}\right)_{i,j=1}^n,$$ where
$s_{\lambda/\mu}$ is the skew Schur function and where $\lambda'$ and $\mu'$ are the conjugate partitions of $\lambda$ and $\mu$.

The traditional proof of this result uses the Lindström–Gessel–Viennot technique to show that the determinant is the sum of nonnegative terms associated with non-intersecting lattice paths, associated with the skew Young tableaux for $\lambda/\mu$. There is also a purely algebraic proof.

Does anyone know if there is a representation theoretic proof of this identity? The skew Schur function $s_{\lambda/\mu}$ is a nonnegative integer linear combination of Schur functions and so $s_{\lambda/\mu}$ should be associated with a group representation.